# Shortest path node question. How to prevent paths from overlapping?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, path

I am trying to create lines that connect point A to point B without overlapping, and I also need the ability to procedurally generate the number of points. So far, I have not been successful in creating lines that avoid overlap, and also didnt know how to set up starting/finishing points like this procedurally. Any ideas? greatly appreciate your assistance!
[image]

So far, I can only set start-finish points by manually saving them to vertex groups in grid. But of course there are easier ways?

Comment: Seems to be one of those things where Python beats nodes. With 3.5 simulation nodes you could loop and process one path after another, and e.g. splitting used edges.

Comment: Hello ! I think this is called a multi-agent pathfinding algorithm and it is not trivial to solve, ie you'll need at least a loop at some point, so it's hard to parallelize (= optimise)

Comment: Thank you for your input @MarkusvonBroady ! So is it possible to generate paths one by one using simulation nodes? For example, by specifying the exact number and position of points?

Comment: I haven't used sim node functionality yet, it's in alpha stage. In principle, it should be possible, though it might differ from your expectations: the easiest solution is to find the shortest path for one point, then split the mesh on the edges used, and continue onto the 2nd point. This means the paths don't cooperate together so not every pair can be connected, for example here you can see how points 12 and 14 have a problem and if the topology is not dense enough they won't find a path. Also the sum of the lengths of all paths will be bigger than optimal https://i.imgur.com/9T2GGWi.png

Comment: It appears to be more challenging than I had anticipated. Maybe someone here has some tips from simulation nodes. Anyway, thanks for the extra clarification @MarkusvonBroady